# React custom hook, counter keeps getting incremented

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React with hooks, I'm trying to create a custom hook for interaction Observer

For this feature here: [Infinite Scroll in react](https://dev.to/hunterjsbit/react-infinite-scroll-in-few-lines-588f)

Since I want for it to be reused multiple times, I want to use it for posts, commments etc

Here is whta I got so far:

**useObserver hook:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useObserver = ({ element, callback }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  console.log('props');
  console.log(page);

  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
  };

  const observerHandler = (entities) => {
    console.log('handle observer');
    const y = entities[0].boundingClientRect.y;
    const target = entities[0];
    if (target.isIntersecting) {
      setPage((counter) => counter + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerHandler, options);
    if (element.current) {
      observer.observe(element.current);
    }
  });

  return [1];
};

export default useObserver;
```

**Parent Component where I use hook:**

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useObserver from './useObserver';


const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  // initiate posts loader
  const loader = useRef(null);

  const [page] = useObserver({ element: loader }); 


  return (
    <div id="post-list">
      <h1> Post list </h1>
      <div class="test" ></div>
      <h1>Show posts</h1>
      <div className="loading" ref={loader}>
        <h1>Loader</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem that I'm having is that state **page** inside of useObserver component get increment always and gets called muliple time continuously, but it should be called only once when user scrolls till that component

Comment: Your use effect has no array, which means that it will run every render.

Answer (score 1):

try keeping an array with element in useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerHandler, options);
    if (element.current) {
      observer.observe(element.current);
    }
  },[element]); //when you specify an empty array it runs only once, an array with value will run when ever the value changes
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer will check it out +1

Comment: Returning the correct cleanup function is pretty important here.